# Not able to access kubernetes service locally

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, kubernetes-service

I am not be able to access my service from my local machine. I had done my k8 deployment using minikube and created a service of NodePort type to access it.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>kubectl get deployments
NAME                 READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
fromk8dashboard      2/2     2            2           25m
```

And the service

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>kubectl get svc
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
fromk8dashboard   NodePort    10.100.68.204    <none>        31000:32058/TCP   26m
kubernetes        ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP           24h
```

When I run the command:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>minikube service fromk8dashboard
|-----------|-----------------|--------------------------|----------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |      NAME       |       TARGET PORT        |            URL             |
|-----------|-----------------|--------------------------|----------------------------|
| default   | fromk8dashboard | tcp-31000-80-6bw28/31000 | http://172.26.75.182:32058 |
|-----------|-----------------|--------------------------|----------------------------|
* Opening service default/fromk8dashboard in default browser...
```

This opens the url "http://172.26.75.182:32058" on browser but it shows **the site cannot be reached**. Am I missing some config or proxy settings?

Another query is, my kubernetes dashboard is running on "http://127.0.0.1:61750/", so shouldn't the service nodeport url be http://127.0.0.1:32058/ or localhost:32058 ?

Describe service returns the below result:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>kubectl describe svc fromk8dashboard
Name:                     fromk8dashboard
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   k8s-app=fromk8dashboard
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 k8s-app=fromk8dashboard
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.100.68.204
Port:                     tcp-31000-80-6bw28  31000/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 tcp-31000-80-6bw28  32058/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.7:80,172.17.0.8:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>



C:\WINDOWS\system32>kubectl describe pod fromk8dashboard-6f98f9468c-wjrd5
Name:           fromk8dashboard-6f98f9468c-wjrd5
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           minikube/172.26.75.182
Start Time:     Tue, 12 May 2020 17:43:05 +0530
Labels:         k8s-app=fromk8dashboard
                pod-template-hash=6f98f9468c
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             172.17.0.8
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/fromk8dashboard-6f98f9468c
Containers:
  fromk8dashboard:
    Container ID:   docker://eef3ecc8e564d9439b66592aa2f1eebd0a886e6380986066ae61bb00193c3687
    Image:          ranjit1827/niguel
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://ranjit1827/niguel@sha256:b9229b2fdc7e5e3e9872189b3840f3c6f23d312af1bff9bbf5a5c68428be5894
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 12 May 2020 17:43:30 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-rn7lm (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-rn7lm:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-rn7lm
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

My service yaml below:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: fromk8dashboard
  namespace: default
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/fromk8dashboard
  uid: 406e99ce-dec1-4e80-91aa-84f75c2d9892
  resourceVersion: '70115'
  creationTimestamp: '2020-05-12T12:13:05Z'
  labels:
    k8s-app: fromk8dashboard
  managedFields:
    - manager: dashboard
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2020-05-12T12:13:41Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:labels':
            .: {}
            'f:k8s-app': {}
        'f:spec':
          'f:externalTrafficPolicy': {}
          'f:ports':
            .: {}
            'k:{"port":31000,"protocol":"TCP"}':
              .: {}
              'f:name': {}
              'f:port': {}
              'f:protocol': {}
              'f:targetPort': {}
          'f:selector':
            .: {}
            'f:k8s-app': {}
          'f:sessionAffinity': {}
          'f:type': {}
spec:
  ports:
    - name: tcp-31000-80-6bw28
      protocol: TCP
      port: 31000
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 32058
  selector:
    k8s-app: fromk8dashboard
  clusterIP: 10.100.68.204
  type: NodePort
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below yaml and you should be to access it via `http://172.26.75.182:30007/`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    k8s-app: fromk8dashboard
  ports:
      # By default and for convenience, the `targetPort` is set to the same value as the `port` field.
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      # Optional field
      # By default and for convenience, the Kubernetes control plane will allocate a port from a range (default: 30000-32767)
      nodePort: 30007
```

Check the [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/) for exposing pod via nodeport service.

Comment: I had set the targetport as 31000 and nodeport as 32058 explicitly that's the reason its showing as 31000:32058/TCP. I also tried with targetport 80 as well.....myservice         NodePort    10.101.223.202   <none>        80:30959/TCP      47m.........but its still not able to access the service and returns site not found.

Comment: add output of kubectl describe svc servicename and share the service and pod yaml in the question. There is no point in setting targetport as 31000 unless the pod is listening on that port.

Comment: sorry, my targetport is 80 and port is 31000.
`

Comment: I have given a yaml in answer..try that

Comment: there seems to be some error(k8-app and protocol) in yaml , however I created a service using https://imgur.com/a/5mjV7c2 . But site not reachable on http://172.26.75.182:31000/

Comment: the labels in the service does not match with pod labels...does Endpoints show pod ip when you describe the service?

Comment: Followed the example in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHvKc6hNmhI&t=3s , with their image and yaml works for me . But when I use my image ranjit1827/niguel and same yaml(with necessary change), it still throws site out of reach. Not sure why but the image when used using > docker run -d --name <somename> -p 81:8080 ranjit1827/niguel and hit  localhost:81 on browser works fine

Comment: your image is listening on port 8080? then the targetPort needs to be 8080 too.